# C# Console - Dynamic Regex Replacement

Tags: c#, regex

I'm with a little problem and didn't find a solution to it, yet.
Well, I'm doing a transpiler and I need to use a Regular Expression that will work until it didn't find any thing more after.
My string is:

```
with System, System.IO, System.Text // and it can go more and more and more
```

And I'm gonna replace EACH one of the thing that is after `with` with Using followed by the name, then, The code would transpile to:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
```

I can do it for a static number, but I don't want to limit them. My current REGEX is

```
"with (.*), (.*), (.*)"
```

Replaced by

```
"using $1;\n using $2;\n using $3;\n"
```

Is there a way to do it dynamic?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex captures all the strings into Group 1:

```
(?:with\s|\G)([^,]*)(?:,\s*|$)
```

Match them all, then iterate the Group 1 captures to build your Using string. Of course this is only one of several ways to do it.

see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wZ3aZ2) (look at the Group 1 captures in the bottom right pane)

**Explain Regex**

```
(?:                      # group, but do not capture:
  with                   #   'with'
  \s                     #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
 |                       #  OR
  \G                     #   where the last m//g left off
)                        # end of grouping
(                        # group and capture to \1:
  [^,]*                  #   any character except: ',' (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
)                        # end of \1
(?:                      # group, but do not capture:
  ,                      #   ','
  \s*                    #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                         #   or more times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
 |                       #  OR
  $                      #   before an optional \n, and the end of
                         #   the string
)                        # end of grouping
```

This sample code outputs what you want (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo)](http://ideone.com/EPy7tq):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
class Program
{
static void Main() {
string s1 = @"with System, System.IO, System.Text";
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?:with\s|\G)([^,]*)(?:,\s*|$)");
var group1Caps = new StringCollection();

Match matchResult = myRegex.Match(s1);
// put Group 1 captures in a list
while (matchResult.Success) {
if (matchResult.Groups[1].Value != "") {
group1Caps.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
}
matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}

string usingStr  = "";
foreach (string match in group1Caps) usingStr = usingStr + "Using " + match + ";\n";
Console.WriteLine(usingStr);

Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();

} // END Main
} // END Program
```

Comment: But adapting your code, it works and solves my problem! Thank you

Comment: @MarceloCamargo They do. Building a C# demo, hang tight. :)

Comment: @MarceloCamargo Added C# code and online demo to build your Using string, check it out. :)

Comment: @MarceloCamargo The [demo](http://ideone.com/EPy7tq) is in C#, and I compiled it in VS2013. Please try to compile the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Capture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get multiple values for a single capturing group:

```
string inp = "with System, System.IO, System.Text";
string repl = Regex.Replace(
        inp, @"^with (?:(?<namespace>.+?)\s*(?:,\s*|$))*$",
            a => String.Join(
                  Environment.NewLine,
                  a.Groups["namespace"]
                    .Captures
                    .OfType<Capture>()
                    .Select(b => String.Format("using {0};", b))
                   )
               );
Console.WriteLine(repl);
```

The contents of `repl` are printed:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
```